# Microsoft Address Validation API

Tags: azure, validation, postman

I'm trying to implement Microsoft Azures Address Validation.
I get it to work using the implicit OAuth v2 but I would like to implement this as a service.

I have added Client Sercets and tried using that method but I don't get an Auth Token back.

Am I not implementing the Auth Service correctly?
Can this API be used with our actual user logging in each time?

[Micorsoft Azure Address Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/address/validate?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

```
[Azure app registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck9oW.png)
[PostMan Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkERQ.png)
[Token Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czeQa.png)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created **Azure AD Application** and added API permissions:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

***To validate the address, I used below query:***

```json
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/validateAddress?api-version=2019-10-01-preview

{
  "addressLine1": "55 110th Ave NE",
  "city": "bellevue",
  "region": "wa",
  "postalCode": "98004",
  "country": "us"
}
```

In **Authorization** tab, paste the access token like below:

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Address - Validate - REST API (Azure Billing)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/address/validate?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)